# New to C, potentially outdated literature keeps referring me to gets() puts(). I need a solid answer

Tags: c

So I am learning C. I do not want to use the gets() and puts() functions due to my compiler says they are dangerous. I look everywhere and they say use fgets() or getc() or getcharacter() I would just like to know what I can do with each. I realize this question has been asked. Heres an example

```
printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
gets("books[ctr].title);
puts("Who is the author? ");
gets(books[ctr].author);
```

Can I use printf() and scanf() instead of get put in above scenario? Also is scanf() useful for strings of characters?

Comment: Great, you know your question is a dupe. Then which part of the answer in the dupe don't you understand?

Comment: could I possibly use scanf() in place of gets() to get string of characters(title of book) from user?

Comment: @Lixor, of course you can

Comment: Im duped....my bad I'll just read all these books

Comment: `puts` is fine.  But never use `gets`.  Use `fgets` instead.  Or, yes, you can use `printf(%s)` instead of `puts`.  And if you really wanted to you could use `scanf` with various format specifiers instead of `fgets`.  (But if you haven't started using `scanf` yet, now's not the time to start.  If you never use `scanf`, always use `fgets`, you'll be happier and more productive in the long run.)

Comment: I understand that it touches memory and cannot be limited in the memory it touches which is why its dangerous. I guess its dangerous because of the ability it has to write over previously written stuff? I apologize. This whole learning C has been fun...I'm just gonna keep trial and error'ing it thanks

Comment: sweet thank you Steve! i'm gonna try fgets

Comment: "Also is scanf() useful for strings of characters?" `scanf()` is not useful if code needs to handle real user input that may not conform to expectations.  IOWs, it does  not do error handling well.  Use `fgets()` to read a line of user input and than parse it with `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc into `books[ctr].title`, `books[ctr].author`.

Comment: How much should I worry about what C standard we're on?

Comment: @ForceBru thank you !

Comment: @Lixor I try not to worry too much about which version of the standard "we" are on.  I'm old-school, so I tend not to make use of newer features that older compilers don't support.  Others will tell you that the latest-and-greatest version is the only one to use.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you! Yea I've decided I'm gonna learn from beginning C89 up ANSI C99. I feel like I could get somewhere with a solid foundation in the old school C. Something tells me my potential future employers feel the same....I hope anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
fgets(books[ctr].title, 40, stdin);
puts("Who is the author? ");
fgets(books[ctr].author, 25, stdin);
puts("How much did the book cost? ");
scanf(" %f", &books[ctr].price);
puts("How many pages in the book? ");
scanf(" %d", &books[ctr].pages);
```

This worked! I'm sorry for bothering with a dumb question, but I've now learned fgets!

Comment: Should use some `sizeof` (or some named constant, e.g. a `#define`-d macro) instead of hard-coding the `40` and `25` size

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you, I will look into that. Hard coding is bad? Or is it just a matter of allocation? Like I must see size with sizeof in order to ensure I do not overflow the data buffer or whatever its called?

Comment: The above code has a structure header file that defines those variables as said values if that helps